# @JsonIgnoreProperties does not ignore `springframework.validation.Errors` that are implicit in the @Validateable object

Tags: json, grails, jackson, spring-validator

I have an object that is annotated with grails.validation.Validateable and that injects an errors object into whatever it annotates. Then I am trying to deserialize this object with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(myJson)`. However, it fails with

`Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.validation.Errors (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

even though I used `@JsonIgnoreProperties(["errors", "Errors"])` on it or `ignoreUnknown = true` as well.

I am assuming this is because the errors is not visible as a class member, but is somehow injected along the way? And thus, maybe JsonIgnoreProperties does not know about it and does not ensure it being ignored?

I even tried adding `Errors errors` member into the class and added `@JsonIgnore` to it, in an attempt to make the implicit errors explicit and ignore it like that, but it didn't change a thing.

What would be recommended here, if I don't want to go for global ignore properties on the objectmapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the top line here:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = ["errors"], allowGetters = true)
@Validateable
public class SomeClass {}
```

The AutoDetect annotation somehow finds out about the hidden "errors" property.
I used allowGetters there, because I wanted to serialize them, but not deserialize them. Custom serializer had to built to achieve that though. You could however just remove `allowGetters` and not deal with errors at all.